# Custom parameters from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

i'm creating a form where a user can choose a product and a quantity. I need to pass the `id` value from the object `@event` to the controller, but i dont know whats the right way to do it. As it is now, it the `params[:event_id]` field is always nil in the controller.

```
 <%= form_tag logic_giveRandomGifts_path :method => 'post' %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= collection_select(:params, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
            Quantidate:
            <%= text_field_tag :quantity, params[:quantity], :size => 2 %>
            <%= submit_tag "GO!",params[:event_id] => @event.id,:class => 'btn btn-default'  %>
          </div>
```

Comment: You can pass value through hidden field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add hidden filed in your form and set its value equal to **@event.id**

```
 <%= form_tag logic_giveRandomGifts_path :method => 'post' %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= collection_select(:params, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true) %>
    Quantidate:
    <%= text_field_tag :quantity, params[:quantity], :size => 2 %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, value: @event.id%> #add this
    <%= submit_tag "GO!",params[:event_id] => @event.id,:class => 'btn btn-default'  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You can use now event id in your controller as **params[:event_id]**

Answer (score 2):

**<%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, @event.id %>**

So this will be available in params[:event_id].

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass an hidden field in form as followings

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :event_id, value: @event.id%>
```

It will available in controller as

```
 params[:event_id]
```